# Redirect google form to different URL based on select option element, but after I submit the form

Tags: wordpress, google-forms

Now am doing on wordpress website. I need to integrate a google form to my website. The problem is , "need to Redirect google form to different URL based on select option element, after I submit the form". There is any plugin for that?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for software recommendations. Consider to try [softwarerecs.se].